# Point in polygon rgeo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geos, rgeo

I need to know if a point is in a polygon or not, in my rails app, in order to to that I wan to use rgeo gem.

To install this geme i folowed the instructions on [rgeo git](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo)

Then I'm sure that GEOS and Proj4 are properly installed.

[image]

I also added this gem 'ffi-geos', no particular reason, only following rgeo doc

Finally I made a test on rails console to check if is working

1. poly_text = "POLYGON ..." (a lot of points, I'm aware that the first point and the last one are the same, otherwise I think this wount work because needs to be a closed polygon)
2. factory = RGeo::Cartesian::Factory (I'm using a cartesian factory because acording to my investigation, if I use a spheric one, this wount work)
3. poly = factory.new().parse_wkt(poly_text)
4. point1 = factory.new().parse_wkt("POINT (0 0)") (this point does not belong to the polygon)
5. poly.within?(point1)
6. result: RGeo::Error::UnsupportedOperation: Method Geometry#contains? not defined.
       from (irb):26

here you can see the output:
[image]

More info:
rails version 5.1.2
ide c9
os ubuntu

if someone has a solution, thanks in advance, I'm also open to use another gem, or whatever, my goal is to solve my point / polygon problem.

Comment: You do not need `ffi-geo` if you have geos install. And I suggest you to use the `RGeo::Cartesian.preferred_factory` method to get you factory (and store it in a constant!).  Finally, I think this particuliar issue on rgeo is fixed now, I would need the original polygon to make sure of that though !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [Geokit](https://github.com/geokit/geokit), just include `gem 'geokit'` in your Gemfile.

Then you will need to create an array of points, where each point is a `Geokit::LatLng`.

For example:

```
points = []
points << Geokit::LatLng.new("-34.8922513", "-56.1468951")
points << Geokit::LatLng.new("-34.905204", "-56.1848322")
points << Geokit::LatLng.new("-34.9091105", "-56.170756")
polygon = Geokit::Polygon.new(points)
polygon.contains? polygon.centroid #this should return true
```

Don't worry about whether or not the first point is the same as the last, the `new` already takes care of that as it is explained [here](https://github.com/geokit/geokit/blob/a66de7e45437394cbd28ea5da0127836ec4f7fe4/lib/geokit/polygon.rb#L10) in the source code.

Comment: Hi Moondaisy, finally I solve this using another factory in the same gem, anyway, it was very dificult to use Rgeo in my prod environment (bluemix), thats why the final soultion was a postgress extension called postgis. Hope this help someone :)

Answer (score 4):

If you just need the point in polygon, there's no need of using a full library. It's pretty simple, and you can scratch freely Geokit's implementation (MIT license):

```
def initialize(points)
    @points = points

    # A Polygon must be 'closed', the last point equal to the first point
    # Append the first point to the array to close the polygon
    @points << points[0] if points[0] != points[-1]
end

def contains?(point)
    last_point = @points[-1]
    oddNodes = false
    x = point.lng
    y = point.lat

    @points.each do |p|
        yi = p.lat
        xi = p.lng
        yj = last_point.lat
        xj = last_point.lng
        if yi < y && yj >= y ||
           yj < y && yi >= y
            oddNodes = !oddNodes if xi + (y - yi) / (yj - yi) * (xj - xi) < x
        end
        last_point = p
    end

    oddNodes
end
```

You can find the whole source code [here](https://github.com/klaxit/geo-resolver/blob/master/lib/geo_resolver/adapters/mapbox_address.rb#L40). And of course, you'll have to create your own class(es) and change a little bit the code.

Answer (score 1):

I had installed the gem before I installed GEOS. Uninstalling and then again installing the rgeo gem worked.